# Pointwise convergence of $(f_n)$ on $I$ to a function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined on an interval $I$ satisfies

1. $|f_n(x) − f_n(y)| \leq |x − y|$ for any $x, y ∈ I$ and any $n \geq 1$ and
2. $(f_n)$ converges pointwise on $I$ to a function $f$.
   Show that $f$ satisfies $|f(x) − f(y)| \leq 2|x − y|$ for all $x, y \in I$.

I have 
$$|f_n(x) − f_n(y)|= |f_n(x) -f(x) − f_n(y) + f(y) +f(x) - f(y)| <
  |f_n(x) -f(x)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)| + |f(x) - f(y)|,$$ 
by triangle inequality.

Since $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$, for $\epsilon >0$  and  $x \in I$  there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|f_n(x) − f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $n\geq N$ and similarly  $|f_n(y) − f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Choose $\epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2}$, so
$$|f_n(x) -f(x)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)| + |f(x) - f(y)|≤ \epsilon + \epsilon + |f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y| + |f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|.$$
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should use the reversed triangle inequality... Or just the fact that the absolute value is continuous.

Comment: What's the issue? You have an $|x-y|$ term and an $|f(x) - f(y)$ term, and you know that this is bounded by $|x-y|$. So the sum is bounded by $2|x-y|$.

Comment: Ahhh thanks! why didn't I see that!! @AlfredYerger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Taken from my comment)

You have an $|x-y|$ term and $|f(x) - f(y)|$, and you know that this latter value is bounded by $|x-y|$, so you can just sum them and have $2|x-y|$.